# Unresponsive virtual OS

Tags: windows-server-2003, virtual-machines, microsoft-virtual-server

Hopefully someone has a suggestion on how to resolve this.

#### Configuration

Host: Win 2003R2 w/Virtual Server 2005R2
Virtual1: Win 2003R2 w/Sql Server 2005
Virtual2: Win 2003R2 w/WSS 3.0

#### Situation

This past weekend the power went out and took down the servers (no UPS, it's a desktop standing in as dev testing server).  Since the servers went down the Virtual2 server after running WSS fairly heavily for an hour to two will become unresponsive via HTTP.  If I login via virtual server's remote control I don't get anything beyond a background screen.  The CPU counter on the virtual server's master status shows that it isn't doing anything.

The only thing I have been able to do is to turn off Virtual2, which loses any state changes.  Shutdown commands issue from the virtual server master status are ignored.  After restarting Virtual2 the event logs and application logs don't indicate what caused the problem.

Anyone have an idea as to how to repair the OS, or maybe what could be the problem?

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

> after running WSS fairly heavily for an hour to two

Is it possible that Virtual2 is filling its (virtual) hard drive?

Since it sounds like it takes a set amount of time to get to the critical 'broken' point, it seems like you should be able to stop services a few at a time to narrow down which one is at fault.

Nothing in the event logs?

Comment: Hadn't thought about a full VHD but that it isn't full, checked the physical drive and it has space also.  I'll have to try the services tomorrow.  Event logs are singularly unhelpful with this (so far).  I'll let you know if I come up with anything else. Thanks.